# Displaying Data in PHP SQL MAX Function

Tags: php, sql, max, die

I can't get this PHP code to work at all.

```
if(!$connecton) {
die("Connection Failed" . $mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("rewiredstate",$connection);

$max="SELECT MAX('Unique ID') as id FROM topics";
$maxquery= mysql_query($max) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($maxquery)) {
echo $row['id'];
}
?>
```

It just says this:

Notice: Use of undefined constant died - assumed 'died' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Opinions\script.php on line 9
died

I have checked the SQL in PHPMyAdmin and that is fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: may be instead of `die()` you have given `died()`;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the alias and id mixed up. Try it this way : `$max="SELECT MAX('id') as UNIQUE_ID FROM topics";`